# How to await Function to finish before executing the next one?

Tags: javascript, node.js

// The Below code already contains the suggestions from the answers and hence works :)

within the below script I tried to fully execute the 'createDatabase' function before the .then call at the end starts to run. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out a solution to achieve just that.

In generell the flow should be as followed:

1. GetFiles - Fully Execute it
2. CreateDatabase - Fully Execute it (while awaiting each .map call to finish before starting the next)
3. Exit the script within the .then call

Thanks a lot for any advise :)

```
const db = require("../database")
const fsp = require("fs").promises
const root = "./database/migrations/"

const getFiles = async () => {
  let fileNames = await fsp.readdir(root)
  return fileNames.map(fileName => Number(fileName.split(".")[0]))
}

const createDatabase = async fileNumbers => {
  fileNumbers.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  for (let fileNumber of fileNumbers) {
    const length = fileNumber.toString().length
    const x = require(`.${root}${fileNumber.toString()}.js`)
    await x.create()
  }
}

const run = async () => {
  let fileNumbers = await getFiles()
  await createDatabase(fileNumbers)
}

run()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database setup successfully!")
    db.end()
    process.exitCode = 0
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error creating Database!", err)
  })
```

The x.create code looks as follows:

```
const dbQ = (query, message) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err.sqlMessage}`)
        return reject()
      }
      console.log(`Success: ${message}!`)
      return resolve()
    })
  })
}

x.create = async () => {
  const query = `
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Country (
      Code CHAR(2) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
      Flag VARCHAR(1024),
      Name_de VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
      Name_en VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,

      Primary Key (Code)
    )`

  const result = await dbQ(query, "Created Table COUNTRY")
  return result
}
```

Comment: Have you forgotten `return` statement in `map`: `return x.create()`?

Comment: @tenbits yep, looks the issue to me

Comment: This doesn't change the sequence in which the code runs though.

Comment: it should, if x.create returns a promise

Comment: oh, right `while awaiting each .map call to finish before starting the next` ... use a for loop with async/await instead of .map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each `x.create` to fully execute before the next one starts, i.e. this is what I interpret where you say `while awaiting each .map call to finish before starting the next` - then you could use async/await with a for loop as follows:

```
const createDatabase = async fileNumbers => {
  fileNumbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  for (let fileNumber of fileNumbers) {
    const x = require(`.${root}${fileNumber.toString()}.js`);
    await x.create();
  })
}
```

However, this also assumes that `x.create()` **returns a Promise** - as you've not shown what is the typical content of `.${root}${fileNumber.toString()}.js` file is, then I'm only speculating

The other interpretation of your question would simply require you to change `createDatabase` so that `promises` is actually an array of promises (at the moment, it's an array of `undefined`

```
const createDatabase = async fileNumbers => {
  fileNumbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const promises = fileNumbers.map(fileNumber => {
    const x = require(`.${root}${fileNumber.toString()}.js`);
    return x.create();
  })
  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Now all `.create()` run in "parallel", but `createDatabase` only resolves onces all promises returned by `x.create()` resolve - again, assumes that `x.create()` returns a promise

Comment: So this way the ".then" will just be called after the whole for-loop got executed for all items? If yes, then my x.create might be messed up :/

Comment: @Architecd - what **is** your `x.create` - that's the key - are you able to show an example in your question? Anyway, the code you *have* shown will need to be changed (to one of the two variations in the answer) since you never "use" the return value of `x.create` in your code

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Your suggestion above (first part) brought me onto the right track. I just fixed the x.create to properly return a promise and it works like a charm now :) I added the full code above in the question for you to see if your interested.